# Fooling R's Method Dispatch

Tags: r, overloading

I am looking for an example where a dot in a function name causes R's Method Dispatch to pick the wrong function. A natural candidate seems to be the builtin function `t.test()`, which should be confused with `t()` when applied to an object of class "test".

Strangely, however, the following code actually calls the transposition function and not `t.test()`:

```
> x <- structure(cbind(1:4,2:5), class="test")
> class(x)
[1] "test"
> t(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    3    4    5
```

This raises two questions:

1. Why is the object transposed and not `t.test()` invoked, as it should be due to the rules of Method Dispatch?
2. What is a (simple) example for messing up the Method Dispatch process by defining a function with a dot inside?

Comment: Interestingly `getS3method()`, inconsistently with actual S3 dispatch, would actually return `t.test` here. I believe that this is a bug (at the very least it should give consistent results!) but when asking about this on the r-devel mailing list I got basically no response, but I got the impression that even (some) core R maintainers do not fully understand S3 dispatch.

Comment: Also, try `registerS3method('t', 'test', t.test)` before calling `t(x)`: it will cause `t.test()` to be invoked. This behaviour changed with R 3.5.

Comment: My "vote," such as it is, would be to force the `stats` library to rename `t.test` to something either without the "dot" (I know, flamewar), or better yet, change the name to something unique and obvious like  `studentT`   .    Since `t.test` is in fact **Not** a method belonging to `t`,  applying `t()` to an overloaded class name should **never** invoke `t.test` because it's not a sub-method of anything.   Is this intended or is it a bug in the interpreter/dispatcher?

Comment: @carl-witthoft There are different methods to define classes in R, and for S4 classes and Reference Classes, you are right. For S3 classes, however, `t.test()` *is* a method of a class "test", provided such a class exists and there is a generic function `t()`. This is just an ambiguity inherent to the S3 way of dealing with classes. Actually, my question was, *how to abuse* this ambiguity for teaching purposes: I want to explain why, e.g., the Google coding style guide discourages the use of dots in function names.

Comment: You say "the rules of Method Dispatch", but didn't say where you read them.  There are mistakes in the manuals that come with R; those are worth reporting to the developers.  There are also mistakes in documentation written by other people.  Sometimes those are worth reporting to those authors, but often it's just not worth the trouble.

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  I don't find it surprising that some of the R Core maintainers don't fully understand S3 dispatch.  It's tricky, it has changed over time, and most of the members of R Core spend very little time looking at or maintaining R internals.

Comment: @cdalitz For what it’s worth, the Google Style guide is a bit rubbish (= some of its items/explanations are at least contentious, if not outright wrong). But other style guides *also* discourage using the dot in names (notably the tidyverse style guide).

Comment: @user2554330 If I remember correctly you were one of the people replying on that mailing list thread; and, just to be clear: I am not unhappy with the answers I received, nor judging your knowledge. All I wanted to convey is that it’s unfortunate that S3 lookup, which is quite central to R, is not exhaustively documented, and that the two different (both core R) implementations of S3 lookup yield different results.

Comment: @konrad-rudolph Just tested my example with R 3.5.1 and, voilà: It results in an error because `t.test()` is called. The requirement to register S3 methods from packages thus apparently was introduced with some later R version.

Comment: @cdalitz Interesting, it’s possible that the relevant change was introduced in 3.6 then: there was a series of progressive changes to the relevant implementation that started with R 3.5 but continued in 3.6.

Comment: The bug in `getS3method()` has reportedly been fixed in the devel version of R, so `getS3method("t", "test")` no longer returns `t.test()`.  It's worth testing it before release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 dispatch is complicated.  If you define a function named `t.test` in the global environment and call `t()` there on an object with class `"test"`, the `t.test()` function will be called.  However, if `t.test` is in a package, it needs to be registered as an S3 method to be handled that way.  (Registration happens in the `NAMESPACE` file or by executing
`registerS3method()`.)

So here's an example of what you are looking for:

```r
t.test <- t.test
x <- 1
class(x) <- "test"
t(x)
#> Error in t.test.default(x): not enough 'x' observations
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

There was some news about this when R 3.5.0 was released in 2018:  the 8th "new feature" from the end in

https://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-3-5-branch/NEWS/2018/03/29#n2018-03-29

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the problem. Just tested it in R 3.51, and there the first line is not needed: even without it, `t.test()` is invoked by `t()`. I thus guess that the hiding of S3 functions in packages was introduced with a later R version. Hints when this happened are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You also have to consider the environment where functions are evaulated. For example, if you ran this in the `stats` environment, you would get

```
t(x)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    2    3    4    5
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "test"

evalq(t(x), envir=asNamespace("stats"))
#   One Sample t-test
# 
# data:  x
# t = 6.4807, df = 7, p-value = 0.0003402
# alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  1.905392 4.094608
# sample estimates:
# mean of x 
#         3
```

So the issue is that the `t()` function is defined in the `base` namespace while `t.test()` is in `stats`. The transpose is found first by default.

Comment: As `stats` comes in the search path before `base`, I thought it should have preference. And in R version 3.5.1 it actually has, and `t()` indeed invokes `t.test()`! It must have to do with the hiding of S3 methods from packages introduced in some later R version, because in R 4.2.1, this no longer works. See the answer by @user2554330.